# Couchbase Mobile (Sync Gateway) sample TODOlite application doesn't replicate; complains _facebook doesn't exist

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

My objective: get https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-iOS syncing with a Couchbase Server and sync gateway on `localhost` rather than the default demo URL.

I run sync gateway like so: `bin/sync_gateway -url http://localhost:8091`

And then the only thing I changed in the example is:

```
-#define kSyncGatewayUrl @"http://demo.mobile.couchbase.com/todolite"
+#define kSyncGatewayUrl @"http://localhost:4984/sync_gateway/"
```

And when I run

```
Error: Error Domain=CBLHTTP Code=404 "404 not_found" UserInfo=0x7ff11941fb50 {NSURL=http://localhost:4984/sync_gateway/_facebook, NSLocalizedFailureReason=not_found, NSLocalizedDescription=404 not_found}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The reason is that I ran `sync_gateway` without enabling Facebook registration support.

Normally this is done in `config.json` file. In fact, [this configuration file was supplied in ToDoLite all along](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-iOS/blob/master/sync-gateway-config.json#L3).

It is crucial that you launch `sync_gateway` with this configuration file. The README actually states this but in a loose and casual way...

```
cd ToDoLite-iOS
sync_gateway -url http://localhost:8091 sync-gateway-config.json
```

NB: I assume above that `sync_gateway` has been made accessible through `$PATH`. It's a good idea to do that anyway.

Also, I didn't pay attention to the `dbname`. So you'll need to replace

```
#define kSyncGatewayUrl @"http://demo.mobile.couchbase.com/todolite"`
```

with

```
#define kSyncGatewayUrl @"http://localhost:4984/todos"
```

---

So, what's the complete sequence of steps to get it working?:

1. If you want to wipe everything on the server, `rm -rf Library/Application\ Support/Couchbase` and start over. Homebrew cask hides this setting somewhere else where it's hard to reset so a manual install is very recommended.
2. Install Couchbase Server
3. Set up login credentials if fresh install; otherwise just login
4. Create a bucket (a database) with name `todos` on the cluster. This is the `dbname` used by TODOLite.
5. Launch sync gateway. Be sure to pass in the replication URL AND the JSON config file.
   `bin/sync_gateway -url http://localhost:8091 sync-gateway-config.json`; keep sync gateway running
6. In the TODOLite `AppDelegate.m`, change `kSyncGatewayUrl`:
     `#define kSyncGatewayUrl @"http://localhost:4984/todos"`. Notice the name of the database is necessary!
7. (Optionally) Access the administrator interface of the sync gateway by going to `http://localhost:4985/_admin/db/sync_gateway/sync`. You can set up the sync function here.

---

In case you're wondering where those port numbers came from, check out

- [ports Couchbase Server uses](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/install-networkPorts.html)
- [ports Sync Gateway uses](http://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/#command-line-tool)

  - 4984 — SG API port
  - 4985 — SG admin server

Comment: Good explanation! Curious what are you building and the use-cases?  Sending an email to hokshunpoon.me

Answer (score 0):

The default remote sync URL will be defined in different files depending on the version of the project you download (iOS, Android, PhoneGap, and Motion). To find the appropriate string to change simply search through your project for the URL "http://demo.mobile.couchbase.com/todolite" and replace it with the URL of your new sync gateway database.